# Merging two columns with survival times into one (loses survival property once merged)

Tags: r, merge, survival-analysis

I am trying to run a cox regression for survival data. I am comparing two groups that have different censoring dates, and now in the dataset I have two columns, one for each survival data (days). In other words, some individuals have their survival data on the first column, while others have the data in the second column.

```
id censorgrp  days1  days2
1      1       30+    NA
2      2       20+    10+
3      1       50+    NA
4      1       35+    NA
5      1       100+    NA
6      2       80+    30
7      2       75+    15
8      2       40+    20+
9      1       30+    NA
10     1       30+    NA
```

In order to run the regression model, I need to combine the two columns into one. Right now I am doing the following:

```
data$newcolumn<-ifelse(data$censorgrp==2,data$days2,data$days1)
```

where censorgrp==2 is the second group, so if the person belongs to the second group, this variable will take the survival data from the second column, otherwise first column for group 1.

However, with this approach, I lose the property of the survival data (i.e., previously the data looked like this "50+", meaning 50 days and was censored, but now it becomes simply "50"). Is there a better way to merge the two columns together? Many thanks.

Comment: What's in the empty spaces in the two columns? `NA`? or blank? By the way you should always add a sample of your data in the question to help answerers.

Comment: Thanks Joe, empty spaces are NA for col2 and other survival data for col1 (the first censoring date was applied for other reasons for the entire dataset, while the second censoring date only applies to a subgroup). Will add a sample shortly, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thanks for the data. You mean you want to keep this `xx+` format? Do you realise the data will be factor not numeric if you keep it like this?

Comment: Yes, i believe coxph only takes survival data and not numeric data

Comment: @KCLC You should re-examine your beliefs (by reading `?Surv`.)  The `survival::coxph`-function takes `Surv`-objects. However these did not appear to be such. A `Surv`-object is a 2-column matrix with the times-values in the first column and the status in the second-column. The `print.Surv` displays the censored values with a trailing "+" but that "+" does not exist in the internal representation.